# Multipart formData testing

Tags: java, integration-testing, multipartform-data

I send request(number 1 on the picture) with image file and inputs(inputs are hidden). My controller looks like that(MealDto has MultipartFile field):

```
@PutMapping("/{id}")
Mono<MealDto> editMeal(@PathVariable String id, @Valid MealDto mealDto) {
    return mealService.updateMeal(id, mealDto);
}
```

Everything works fine, so I wanted write some tests. I read image from desktop and used MultipartBodyBuilder:

```
File file = new File("C:\\Users\\xxx\\Desktop\\2.jpeg");
        ByteArrayResource byteArrayResource = new ByteArrayResource(Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath())) {

            @Override
            public String getFilename() {
                return "2.jpeg";
            }

        };

MultipartBodyBuilder bodyBuilder = new MultipartBodyBuilder();
bodyBuilder.part("name", update.getName());
bodyBuilder.part("recipe", update.getRecipe());
bodyBuilder.part("description", update.getDescription());
bodyBuilder.part("imageToSave", byteArrayResource, IMAGE_JPEG);

webTestClient.put().uri(URI)
                .body(BodyInserters.fromObject(bodyBuilder.build()))
                .exchange()
                .expectStatus().isOk();
```

Number 2 on image what I send with webTestClient and what error I got (number 3 on picture).
Without image in bodybuilder it works fine - but I want to test case with image.

[image]